# Anonymous declarations can’t be renamed - Xcode 7.1.1

Tags: c, xcode, macos, refactoring, xcode7

I get this message while trying to rename `first_layer` field in struct:

```
typedef struct{

        long layers_count;

        CannLayer **layers;
        CannLayer *first_layer;
        CannLayer *last_layer;

}Cann;
```

Above definition is located in one of *.h (C header file) of Mac OS project (not iOS).

Answer (score 0):

What's your question?

Also, you should add in the first declaration of your struct.

tl;dr when you're typedef'ing a struct in C, you have to do this:

```
typedef struct StructName {
    uint8_t Example;
} StructName;
```